# Get road segment true bearings in QGIS

Tags: qgis, bearing

I am working on a city-planning research project using QGIS. For a given area of interest, I have downloaded an open street map layer (the 'highway' keys) with all the roads in that area.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Determine how many kilometers of road in the OSM layer are within +/- `x` degrees of true north (ie. for all the road segments in the map, which of them are within some tolerance of true north).
2. Create a new layer containing just the road segments that were found within (1) above.

My preference is to do this programmatically in python.

I am relatively new to QGIS, what would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Are you asking which tools to use, how to break down the task, or how to do this using Python?

Comment: I understand how to do tasks like counting the number of roads inside the area bound by a separate polygon layer (ie. the area of interest). How does one go about creating a new OSM layer containing only the road segments that line up with true north?

Comment: With regards the Python, I just want to do this operation repeatedly on a number of areas of interest for comparison purposes, so giving the solution in Python would help with that

Comment: I strongly suggest you break down the process into single tasks and do some research as to how to achieve each step. Also, when asking for coding advice, it is site policy you have to provide coding attempts.

Comment: OK, how do you select the road segments within a tolerance of true north?